# How to turn on WD Smartware?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, macbook, finder

I just used the following line in my MacOS X Macbook and got the WD Smartware finally not to appear on my Finder:

```
sudo sh -c "echo UUID=`diskutil info /Volumes/WD\ SmartWare/ | grep 'UUID' | awk '{print $NF}'` none hfs rw,noauto 0 0 >> /etc/fstab"
```

I am still hoping to get rid totally of that virtual disc somehow. I got that feeling that I actually need to see the Virtual Disc in order to try other things.

Please, advice how can I turn on the Smartware, make it again appear on the Finder. Sorry, I don't understand the code and have a very little idea of what it does. Seems like I will need to study each command just to return everything to previous stage. Actually the command works well. I just was not sure if I need to hide and was in a rush to make my My Book clean and working.  Can you please, provide one line to revert previous action.

---

I am not a Windows user and need help from someone who knows Mac, Linux to help me to reverse an effect caused by that line:

sudo sh -c "echo UUID=`diskutil info /Volumes/WD\ SmartWare/ | grep 'UUID' | awk '{print $NF}'` none hfs rw,noauto 0 0 >> /etc/fstab"

making Virtual CD invisible. I know it's there and I want to be able to see it again. Cheers.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Answer (score 1):

According to WD, it is impossible to actually remove the WD smartware from the drive. The most that can be done is to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done by:

```
sudo sh -c "echo UUID=diskutil info /Volumes/WD\ SmartWare/ | grep 'UUID' | awk '{print $NF}' none hfs rw,noauto 0 0 >> /etc/fstab"
```

Is made an entry into the file /etc/fstab. In fact, you've not only made an entry, you've probably created an entirely new file.

To reverse this, simply open up a Terminal and do:

```
$ cd /etc
$ sudo rm fstab
```

This will delete the /etc/fstab file effectively undoing the earlier command.

You may want to make a back-up copy first:

`$ sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak`

There's no way of permanently removing the SmartWare partition unfortunately.

Comment: @Dimitri - Did this answer help you at all?